# meaning of nginx user directive

Tags: nginx

A nginx is installed on AWS EC2 running ubuntu 14.04. the `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` first line says `user www-data;`.
Is there such a system user on my EC2 instance? if not. what value is given to this directive? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "user" directive defines with which user Nginx will run the web server process. You may start Nginx with root, but it will launch sub processes owned by the specified user.

If the www-data user does not exist, you can create it. Or, you can specify any other user. But it is better that a web server has a dedicated user, for the sake of security.

On my server I created a "www" user with group "www" and used it in my Nginx configuration.

Comment: Why does nginx need a User?

Comment: @SreekarMouli It is recommended to have a specific non-privileged user for your web server or any other service that can be accessed from outside your server (database, ftp, mail...), for example if there is a security flaw in your web server or web application, you don't want its processes to be run as root... Imagine if an attacker succeed to upload some php files in your server, then he could do anything he wants... Whereas with a specific user, he could do only what this specific user can do.